# How to mock readonly property in nodejs using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I have the following class which has a chunk defined as an array and multiple objects get pushed into this array `this.chunk`.

**SearchController.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchController {
  private chunk: any[] = [];
  readonly CHUNK_SIZE: number = 100;

  public async post(names) {

    this.chunk.push(names);

    if (this.chunk.length >= this.CHUNK_SIZE) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

  }
}
```

I want to be able to either mock the CHUNK_SIZE to a number equal to 1 or maybe be able to change the value of the `chunk.length`

Below is my test

SearchController.test.ts

```
  it('should return true for chunk_size 1', async () => {

    const actual = await queue.post({action: 'UPDATE'});


    expect(actual).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I have tried using jest.spyOn() but it didn't work.
What am I missing?

Would really appreciate if anyone can help. thanks.

Comment: SearchController['CHUNK_SIZE'] is it?

Comment: @deko_39 what do you mean?

Comment: use SearchController['CHUNK_SIZE'] = xxx in the testing code when you need to mock that property

Comment: @deko_39 I can't, because CHUNK_SIZE is readonly

`Cannot assign to 'CHUNK_SIZE' because it is a read-only property.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following trick inside of `it` block:

```js
Object.defineProperty(<instanceOfController>, 'CHUNK_SIZE', { value: <anyRandomValue>, writable: false });
```

For example:

```js
it('should return true for chunk_size 1', async () => {
  Object.defineProperty(queue, 'CHUNK_SIZE', { value: 1, writable: false });

  const actual = await queue.post({ action: 'UPDATE' });
  expect(actual).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My technique for such cases is to create a derived test-specific class:

```
class SearchControllerTest extends SearchController {
  override readonly CHUNK_SIZE = 1; // property cannot be private in parent class
}
```

… and then mock the *SearchController.ts* module with the new class. If necessary, I use `jest.requireActual()` to get the true value of the module.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to trick the typings with `any` and use bracket accessor `['someprop']` to redefine the property:

```
(queue as any)['CHUNK_SIZE'] = 1
```